# rmarkdown when I print table in a loop adds "Loading [MathJax]/extensions/MathZoom.js" to my pdf

Tags: r-markdown, kableextra

I am trying to make a pdf with tables using a loop in rmarkdown.
But I get this "Loading [MathJax]/extensions/MathZoom.js" added to the bottom of the pdf.

How do I get rid of this message?
Here is my rmd code

---

### title: "Some tables"
output: html_document

```
for(i in 1:2){
  mytable = kbl(head(mtcars))
  cat( print(mytable))
}
```

I make the pdf by typing the following in the console (typically I run this from another R program).

library(kableExtra)
rmarkdown::render("tables_in_loop.rmd")
pagedown::chrome_print("tables_in_loop.html")

How do I get rid of the loading message?
When I just use

```
 kbl(head(mtcars))
```

I don't get the message but I want to print out lots of tables with a loop.

I know Rmd can do pdfs, but I get an error about running pdflatex.exe from
C:\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32
I don't have administrative rights to execute this. If you have suggestions about this they are much appreciated.

Also I have a 64 bit windows 10 computer and I'm running R in 64.

Thank you so much,
Jennifer

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I need to just use cat(mytable) not cat(print(mytable))